# Spring Boot 2 Actuator /health and /info returns HTTP 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've added dependencies in `pom.xml` to the brand new Spring Boot app, as described in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-enabling)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and added the following properties to the `application.yml` in order to just expose `/health` and `/info` endpoints

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - info
          - health
      jmx:
        exposure:
          exclude: "*"
  endpoint:
    info:
      enabled: true
    health:
      enabled: true
```

but can't reach the mentioned endpoints on running app via `localhost:8080/health` and `localhost:8080/info` - there is HTTP 404 response.

Am I missing something? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: if your application runs on `localhost:8080/` (no context path), it should work/is hard to say, what is missing... the config matches the defaults/can be omit, except that `jmx` part, which seems also to be bad indented (at least in the post).

Comment: I think the URL should be http://localhost:8080/your_context_path/actuator/health

Comment: @RebaiAhmed you are quite right! finally, I've found it in https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/. If you want - specify it in separate answer so that I could mark as solution, or I will answer by myself otherwise. Thank you!

Comment: You can make it your answer :) @DmitryAdonin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible configurations that could change Actuator /health and /info endpoints:

First, the **spring boot mvc server**, assume you have it like this:

```
server:
   port: 8080
   servlet:
      context-path: /test
```

Second, the **Actuator management server**:

```
management:
  server:
  #port: #don't change it, then the port for actuator will be the same as server.port above
  endpoints:
     web:
       base-path: /actuator  #the default value for sring boot 2.x is /actuator, even you don't specify it, don't forget to include this in the URL
       exposure:
          include: "*"
  endpoint:
     health:
       show-details: always
```

So the right URLs to access Actuator should be :

```
http://localhost:8080/test/actuator/info

http://localhost:8080/test/actuator/health
```

On the whole, the URL pattern to visit Actuator endpoints should be:

```
http://localhost:{server.port}/{server.servlet.context-path}/{management.endpoints.web.base-path}/**
```

You can compare your configurations with this example to see what's causing the 404 error.

Comment: @Qui Zhou you are quite right! finally, I've found it in spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service, it's a bit strange that it wasn't mentioned in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: Glad you have solved the issue! I actually learnt that by reading the doc [Spring Boot Actuator: Production-ready Features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints) (it actually metioned the /actuator prefix), and  then did some practices to verify that.

Comment: Another point to be noted is that the default path of an actuator endpoint will be different based on whether spring boot 1.X is used, versus 2.X. For example, in 1.X the default actuator health endpoint is just `[context-root]/health`, while in 2.X the path is `[context-root]/actuator/health`.

Comment: @sandboxbohemian Good point ! It's because in spring boot 1.x, the default value for `management.endpoints.web.base-path` is `/`